# how to capture only http with tcpdump with linux

Tags: linux, http, tcpdump

First I capture all data with : `tcpdump -i any  -s 0 -w /tmp/http.cap`

no I want capture 'only http'

I tried to add : and port http

But it is incorrect.

thanks

Comment: did you try sudo tcpdump -i any -s 0  'port http' ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check this:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 'tcp port http' -w /tmp/http.cap
```

Comment: tcpdump says: unknown port http. Any suggestions?

Comment: put the port number in place of the word http, like 80 or 8080.

Comment: @Gediminas - You can read it with `tcpdump -r /tmp/http.cap` and you can even apply more `tcpdump` filters in that command: `tcpdump -r /tmp/http.cap 'src net 10.0.0.0/24'` would show only stuff from that netblock. You can also take that file and open it up in wireshark on your desktop for a GUI experience. Finally, are you sure you really want ALL the http traffic? If you can pair it down by interface, or port, or source IP it'll be a lot easier to read.